# Raspberry Pi Python Talkey (TTS) + Cron

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech

I have written this little Python script to listen to the BBC RSS Top Stories feed on my Raspberry Pi

So first of all because I have problems with the 3.5 mm Jack (no sound), I went into

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then in Advanced Options > Audio I chose "Force 3.5 mm ('headphone') jack"

(This always works for me)

So the jack configuration out of the way, let's check out the script:

```
# morning.py

import feedparser # To scrape the BBC Feed
import talkey # The TTS service I'll be using

d = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml")
tts = talkey.Talkey(
    engine_preference=['espeak'],
    espeak={
        'deafults': {
            'words_per_minute': 100,
            'variant': 'f4',
       }
   }
)
for entry in d.entries:
    tts.say(entry.title + ":" + entry.summary)
```

I wanted the script to run at a specific time (morning) so I used Cron -a task manager for Linux. This is what I typed in

```
crontab -e
0 8 * * * sudo python morning.py >/dev/null 2>&1 # inside crontab
```

(The morning.py script is located in the 'pi' directory.)

However the script will not run at the specified time for some reason.

(It runs perfectly without Cron though.)

Comment: Figured it out: had to locate the directories

Comment: Good to see you solved it yourself! Note you can answer your own post as described in [Can I answer my own question?](/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to initialize crontab temporary shell with commands like:

```
pulseaudio --start
pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.platform-es8316-sound.analog-stereo
```

This is an example for Rock Pi 4 B.